# vertex ai matching service machines

Tags: google-cloud-vertex-ai

i want to try vertex ai vector matching service but when i do the deployment it always puts n 16 machines on my index. i want to try with something smaller but i dont see option to specific machine type during deployment.
here is my deployment command:

```
gcloud ai index-endpoints deploy-index 2056746450917785600 \
  --deployed-index-id=postanndeploy \
  --display-name=smallindexdeploy \
  --index=5486800517113839616 \
  --min-replica-count=1 \
  --max-replica-count=2 \
  --project=myproject \
  --region=us-central1
```

after i am done deploying when i look at deployment i see n16 machine. which is way bigger than i need for my POC. is there a way i can do it in smaller machine and not worry about costs.

Manish

Answer (score 1):

The machine type for a matching engine deployment will depend on the sharding level you set while creating the index. The default sharding if nothing is specified is `SHARD_SIZE_MEDIUM`.

`SHARD_SIZE_MEDIUM` uses `e2-standard-16` machines by default. You can try with `SHARD_SIZE_SMALL` for smaller use cases. The number of machines spinned will depend on the size of the index. The machines used for `SHARD_SIZE_SMALL` will be `e2-standard-2` instance.

However, the number of such instances spinned up will depend up on your overall index size. The matching engine monitoring dashboard will tell you how many instances are created for your specific index.

You can find more docs from google related to the index size and instances [here](https://cloud.google.com/vertex-ai/docs/matching-engine/create-manage-index#create-index).

Answer (score 1):

I'm new to vertex AI as well, I have set the `SHARD_SIZE_SMALL` while creating the index using API.

```
requests.post("https://us-central1-aiplatform.googleapis.com/v1/projects/PROJECT_ID/locations/us-central1/indexes", json.dumps({
    "displayName": DISPLAY_NAME,
    "description": DISPLAY_NAME,
    "metadata": {
       "contentsDeltaUri": INPUT_GCS_DIR,
       "config": {
          "dimensions": 768,
          "approximateNeighborsCount": 150,
          "shardSize": "SHARD_SIZE_SMALL",
          "distanceMeasureType": "DOT_PRODUCT_DISTANCE",
          "featureNormType": "UNIT_L2_NORM",
          "algorithmConfig": {
             "bruteForceConfig": {}
          }
       },
    },
}), headers={
    "Authorization": f"Bearer {TOKEN[0]}"
})
```

But still, it was launching the `n2-standard-16` machine when I deployed the index.
After a little bit of research, I found out we can specify the machine type while deploying the index.

```
deployed_index = index_endpoint.deploy_index(
    index=index,
    deployed_index_id=INDEX_ID,
    machine_type="e2-standard-2",
    max_replica_count=1,
    min_replica_count=1,
)
```

Hope this helps